# Temporary Table creation Issue in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I create and insert values into a temporary table, I got this error in a SQL Server 2005 database.

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
> Incorrect syntax near ','

But when I run the exact code in SQL Server 2008 and higher versions, I can successfully create the rows.

Is there a limitation in OLDER VERSION? or just some setting issues?

These are my codes as example

```
create table #CustCodesMapping 
(
     NewCustCode varchar(30), 
     OldCustCode varchar(30) collate database_default
)

insert into #CustCodesMapping
values ('11111', 'aaaaa'), ('22222', 'bbbbb'), ('33333', 'ccccc')
```

but when I only add one value, it works

```
create table #CustCodesMapping 
(
     NewCustCode varchar(30), 
     OldCustCode varchar(30) collate database_default
)

insert into #CustCodesMapping
values ('11111', 'aaaaa')
```

Comment: Why are you still using SQL Server 2005, it's been completely unsupported for 5~ years now; long past time to upgrade.

Comment: Hi, i need to extract and run  query from an old server.. that's why

Comment: And *that* server should have been upgraded about 5 years ago.

Comment: SQL Server 2005 doesn't support specifying *multiple tuples* of data after the `values` keyword - you need to write a separate `insert into .... values (...)` for each tuple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reiterate my comment:

> Why are you still using SQL Server 2005, it's been completely unsupported for 5~ years now; long past time to upgrade.

As for the problem, again, it's because you're using such an outdated version of SQL Server. `VALUES` allowing multiple rows was introduced in SQL Server 2008 (which is also, completely unsupported). You have to use the *really* old method in 2005:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #CustCodesMapping (NewCustCode varchar(30),
                                OldCustCode varchar(30) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT);
INSERT INTO #CustCodesMapping (NewCustCode,OldCustCode)
SELECT '11111',
       'aaaaa'
UNION ALL
SELECT '22222',
       'bbbbb'
UNION ALL
SELECT '33333',
       'ccccc';
```

But the *real* solution is upgrade to a supported version. Unfortuantely, as you're using 2005, that means 2 upgrades. 2005 -> 2012 -> supported version.